# shape.intersects function - behavior

Tags: java

i have this code:

```
public class Intersect extends JFrame {
private boolean collision = false;

public Intersect() {
    add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Shape oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 200, 200);
            Shape rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(200, 200, 200, 200);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.draw(oval);
            g2.draw(rect);
            if(oval.intersects(rect.getBounds())) {
                System.out.println("contact");
                collision = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    });
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Intersect i = new Intersect();
    i.setVisible(true);
    if(i.collision == true)
        System.out.println("boom");
    else System.out.println("no boom");
}
```

}
result in console:"
no boom
contact
contact
contact"
program keep false value in variable collision for all the time, but why it print "contact" if it dont change variable collision to true? (in condition if(oval.intersects(rect.getBounds())))

Answer (score 1):

Painting happens asynchronously in response to requests from the operating system to paint the window. It doesn't happen immediately when you call `setVisible(true);`.

So it *does* set the `collision` variable to true. It just hasn't happened *yet* at the time the code in `main` runs. This is why "contact" is printed after "no boom".

Edit: The way I'd suggest fixing it is to separate the collision logic from the painting code. E.g., declare the Shapes as fields on the frame, so they are available outside the paint method:

```
class Intersect extends JFrame {
    private Shape oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 200, 200);
    private Shape rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(200, 200, 200, 200);
```

The panel's painting method becomes simply:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.draw(oval);
    g2.draw(rect);
}
```

Then remove the collision variable and make it a method so you can call it at any time:

```
boolean collision() {
    return oval.intersects(rect.getBounds());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Intersect i = new Intersect();
    i.setVisible(true);
    if (i.collision())
        System.out.println("boom");
    else System.out.println("no boom");
}
```

Note: There is another (potential) problem with this code. All GUI-related activity is supposed to happen on a dedicated thread, the event dispatch thread. [The `main` method should switch to the event dispatch thread before creating the GUI.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) To do this, change the beginning of `main` to this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main(args);
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    Intersect i = new Intersect();
    ...
```

That will re-call main on the GUI thread.

Comment: Thanks to explanation, but can you help me how to solve that?